# How can I fix a hole in the internal brick of a cavity wall?

Tags: brick, plaster

An electrician was trying to dig out my wall and he just left it like this. He told me he'd come back and fill it with expanding foam. Is this the best way? I was also advised I could use sand & cement but I don't know I can fill it with it being hollow on the inside.

Any advice is much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: That loose cable might be the bigger problem, most places do not allow non protected cable outside of walls.  Filling that hole should not be hard.  Matching the wall finish/make it look decent might be.

Comment: Context, please. What room is this? What are your standards for appearance? Please revise to add detail about the situation. Take the [tour] and see the [help] for tips.

Comment: How old is this wall?. Old lime-mortar walls have constraints newer cement-mortar walls don't.